# How to use TEX $$\begin{array}{l} ... \end{array}$$ inside a quote?

Tags: support, markdown, latex

I want to use a TEX-formatted content inside a quote. But the following code does not work:

```
> $$\begin{array}{l}
> a = b,\\
> c = d
> \end{array}$$
```

How to solve this?

Comment: But where can I ask this question? What is the site dedicated to markdown formatting questions on SE sites?

Comment: Seems to me that this is on-topic here. I mistook it for a general question about TeX at first.

Comment: @lyricallywicked: You *could* try [TeX.SE], but honestly Meta SE should be, and generally is, capable of handling at least some basic support questions about mixing the MathJax SE uses for TeX formatting with SE's Markdown dialect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need one ">" at the beginning of the whole Tex Array, otherwise it messes up the Tex if you put the ">" at the beginning of each line.

```
> $$\begin{array}{l}
a = b,\\
c = d
\end{array}$$
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried copying and pasting the original version of this into an answer (which I didn't submit) and it looked okay in the preview. All except for the second line which didn't show two trailing backslashes. (I had to type three of those characters in order to produce two in the preview, so it must be interpreting it as an escape character in some way. This problem occurred regardless of the starting greater than sign.) I wish the question would indicate *how* the code doesn't work.